# SQL get first matching results

Tags: sql, asp-classic, odbc, netezza

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM myTable
WHERE 
ID LIKE 'R43%' OR 
ID LIKE 'D32%' OR 
ID LIKE 'F22%'
```

and ID might have values such as:

```
ID
____

R431
R431
R432
R434
D322
D322
D327
F226
F227
```

How would I only get the records for the first ID matched? Like for the values above, I would only get records for (R431, R431, D322, D322, F226). The ID values in the table I'm grabbing from are sequential (so R432's will always appear after R431s in the table).

Comment: what do you mean by first ID matched?

Comment: Is NAME tied to the ID, so ALL records with ID R431 would have the same NAME?  It's a subtle difference, but it matters when ordering and filtering.  I'm thinkning the answer lies in using MAX with Group By to get the correct fields, but without more info on the exact schema at the table, it's hard to guess what to group.order by.  In your limited sample, DISTINCT would work, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidCheung I mean the first ID value found for a search string like "D32%". So if "D322" is matched first, only records with ID=D322 would be returned

Comment: @DavidStratton no, names can be unique for all ids so I cannot assume R431s would all have the same name values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Oracle Analytical functions for these kind of queries

```
    select * from (
select id , substr(id,0,3),rank() over ( partition by substr(id,0,3) order by id) rank 
from mytable
WHERE ID LIKE 'R43%' OR ID LIKE 'D32%' OR ID LIKE 'F22%')
where rank = 1
```

Comment: I would chnage that to `PARTITION BY id`. Chopping to 3 characters is arbitrary. What if there is an `R431156` id?

Comment: I used substr as OP was using only first 3 characters to match in the where clause.

Comment: Would be interesting to know how the snippets are executed on the Netezza appliance for this one. Looks like you're hitting full tablescans here, you might be able to speed it up further, if performance starts being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a MIN query and a nested subquery should get you what you want.

```
Select ID, 
       Name 
FROM myTable 
WHERE 
     ID IN ( 
       SELECT MIN(ID) From myTable WHERE ID LIKE 'R43%' OR  ID LIKE 'D32%' OR  ID LIKE 'F22%'     
           )
```

*If there's another field you want to key off, like OrderDate, etc, change the subquery.  Either way, the outer query will only select records from the IDs selected in the inner query.*

Comment: I don't think that does what he describe here: "Like for the values above, I would only get records for (R431, R431, D322, D322, F226)."

Comment: Edited based on comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME FROM myTable
WHERE 
ID LIKE 'R43%' OR 
ID LIKE 'D32%' OR 
ID LIKE 'F22%'
```

Comment: I don't think that does what he describes here: "Like for the values above, I would only get records for (R431, R431, D322, D322, F226)."

Comment: This was based on my interpretation of his requirement. I may have misread.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery:

```
SELECT R.ID AS ID, R.NAME AS NAME FROM myTable R
WHERE 
R.ID LIKE 'R43%'
AND R.ID IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
 FROM myTable A
 WHERE A.ID LIKE 'R43%'
 ORDER BY A.ID
 LIMIT 1
)

UNION 

SELECT D.ID AS ID, D.NAME AS NAME FROM myTable D
WHERE  
D.ID LIKE 'D32%'
AND D.ID IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT B.ID
 FROM myTable B
 WHERE B.ID LIKE 'D32%'
 ORDER BY B.ID
 LIMIT 1
)

UNION

SELECT F.ID AS ID, F.NAME AS NAME FROM myTable F
WHERE  
F.ID LIKE 'F22%'
AND F.ID IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT C.ID
 FROM myTable C
 WHERE C.ID LIKE 'F22%'
 ORDER BY C.ID
 LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY returns an arbitrary row. I think he wants the "first" row, which I assume is one of a) the row that was inserted into the table first b) the one with the lowest number or c) the one which occurs first with a lexicographic order (the OP unfortunately didn't specify which of these three options he wants). Also, it would be better if you didn't have to duplicate a huge section of code `n` times.